# Java - Finding a certain number on a website

Tags: java, url, bufferedreader

What would the method be to find a number after a String of text

Example would be the latest version of something.

So basically it would open up a URL, use the BufferedReader and search for a String of text. The number (int / double) would be found after the String and the program would compare the latest version with the current version.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: use html parser library, such jsoup: http://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 1):

Using an HTML parser like @qrtt suggested is a good idea. But you could also do the following. Take the entire response from the page, and use regex to find your string

The regex would be something like `/string_of_text=[0-9]*/g`
That would return the string of text along with the number after it, which you can use, with a  little string manipulation.

Comment: You could use a positive look behind so the regex only returns the number and then you won't have to do any extra string manipulation `(?<=string_of_text)[0-9]*`

Comment: See some of the examples [**here**](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#examples). It is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You need a parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) to parse your content into tokens. Then run a search using regex. I'm not too good with regex so maybe you can use [txt2re.com](http://txt2re.com) for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I used substrings to find where the "version = X" was and then just parsed  for the double

Comment: If you found a solution that worked for you , accept the answer,even if it is your own to indicate to others you solved it and to help others if having same issue.